# Unable to create and save txt file

Tags: android, string, file, kotlin, directory

I am simply trying to create a .txt file with the phrase "Today snow is falling." in it

I get an error with the code below:

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/mywork/test.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`

I am completely flabbergasted, what's wrong with my code? How can I fix?

```
import java.io.File

val fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/mywork/test.txt"
val myfile = File(fileName)

val content = "Today snow is falling."

myfile.writeText(content)
```

Comment: What part of *permission denied* is unclear? Your app doesn't have permissions to write to the folder where you're trying to save the file.

Comment: @KenWhite But I've given my app storage permission

Comment: The error message *permission denied* says otherwise. Also, have you created the folder `mywork` before trying to write to it?

Comment: @KenWhite Yes the folder `mywork` already exists

Comment: @KenWhite I forgot to add this permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`. Now it works, but I don't understand why it's required since camera apps apparently don't need to need it to save photos. How do camera apps save pictures without needing this permission?

Comment: A camera app I installed required that I give it permissions, as did a video editing app.

Comment: Take a look at this one from Google: https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/CameraXBasic It doesn't ask for that permission

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not installing an app to see if it requires permissions or not. It's pretty clear that it would, based on the behavior of your own code and the solution you found. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you for your reply, but there's no need to install, just look at the AndroidManifest.xml file: https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/main/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml As you can see, it does not ask for that storage permission.

Comment: @iamhere Please read about Storage Access Framework: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files and if you read your linked github project, you would have seen that it is using AndroidX `FileProvider`: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider